# Python: How to get the name of an Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

A coworker who is on vacation has code that is similar to, for example:

```py
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

def lookup(enum_type: Enum, value: str) -> Any:
    try:
        return enum_type[value]
    except ValueError:
        # PROBLEM IS HERE
        enum_name = ???
        raise ConfigurationError(enum_name, value)
```

Given an `Enum` like this, is there any way to retrieve its name? In this case, I would like to have `enum_name = 'MyEnum'`. We could do some parsing if necessary, but it would be very handy to just be able to get the name of the `Enum`.

In addition, PyCharm is giving me a warning on the lookup in:

```py
return enum_type[value]
```

with suggestion:

```
Ignore an unresolved reference enum.Enum.__getitem__
```

Any help to clean this up would be appreciated.
We are using Python 3.10. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-python/ its just .value if you are trying to return the int value or .name if you are trying to return the variable name

Comment: `enum_type: Enum` annotates `enum_type` as an *instance* of `Enum`, not an enum class.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at typing, and `Enum` is not listed there, so it doesn't really make sense to include it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the enum would be `enum_type.__name__`.

Be aware that the square bracket look-up (i.e. `enum_type[value]`) is actually looking up by member name, not member value.  Member value would be `enum_type(value)`.

Comment: Thank you. That did exactly what I wanted it to. I'm aware of the [] and () syntax with Enums but this instance seemed like it was acting weird and mentioning EnumMeta.